# Change to name identification on Google maps

Tags: google-maps

The original building owner's name comes up when viewing the map (Ducoing auto /RV sales). How can we get our name, Hale Glass, Inc., to appear? The address in question is 1910 Estelle Lane Placentia, CA 92870

Answer (score 0):

This is something that you have to contact Google about. You can request they change information like this on this support page: http://maps.google.com/support/bin/request.py

Look for the link that says "I see incorrect business information for emergency services, hospitals or shelters"